# Is this a normal number of database connections?

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql, database, connections, amazon-lightsail

Check out this graph of my database connections. I am running a Postgres database on Lightsail, and I am connecting to it from a single Ubuntu instance running a single instance of Express and Sequelize. While I'm very comfortable with all of this from a coding perspective, I don't know shit about this from a devops perspective, so I am a little confused by the number of database connections.

You can see that in the past it has spiked to nearly 400. I haven't experienced any performance issues, and when I look at the CPU utilization over the same period, there is nothing concerning at all. But still I am wondering if the number of connections is normal. From my very dumb understanding of the issue, I am using Sequelize as an ORM, and I am using the default connection pool (5), so it seems that there would only ever be up to 5 simultaneous connections.

[image: Database connections over one week]

Comment: The graph clearly states that these are the sum of database connections over a period of time, not the number of concurrent or simultaneous connections.

Comment: @joeqwerty thanks, that's interesting that they present it this way. They don't offer a metric of concurrent connections which seems like it would be a little more useful.